# Java Graphs: Cannot properly implement addEdge() method to weighted undirected graph

Tags: java, data-structures, graph

Im using the following code from a Java book to implement the weighted unidrected graph version.

Vertex.Java

```
public class Vertex<T> {

    /**
     * Client-supplied vertex information.
     */
    protected T info;         

    /**
     * Neighbors of this vertex.
     */
    protected List<Neighbor> neighbors;  

    /**
     * Initializes a new instance with vertex information.
     * 
     * @param vertexInfo Vertex information.
     */
    protected Vertex(T vertexInfo) {
        info = vertexInfo;
        neighbors = new List<Neighbor>();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if ((other != null) && (other instanceof Vertex)) {
            Vertex another = (Vertex)other;
            return (info.equals(another.info));
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Neighbor.Java -> object that stores the weight and number of a vertex

```
public class Neighbor {

    /**
     * Internal vertex number of neighbor.
     */
    public int vertexNumber;
    public int weight;

    /**
     * Initializes a new instance with given vertex number.
     * 
     * @param vertexNum Vertex number.
     */
    public Neighbor(int vertexNum) {
        vertexNumber = vertexNum;
    }
    //constructor for weighted neighbour
    public Neighbor(int vertexNum, int weight){
        vertexNumber = vertexNum;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if ((other != null) && (other instanceof Neighbor)) {
            Neighbor another = (Neighbor)other;
            return (vertexNumber == another.vertexNumber);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

DirGraph.Java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class DirGraph<T> {

    /**
     * Array of Vertex instances (vertex info and adjacency list)
     */
    protected ArrayList<Vertex<T>> adjlists;     

    /**
     * Initializes a new directed graph instance of default initial vertex capacity.
     */
    public DirGraph() {
        adjlists = new ArrayList<Vertex<T>>();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes a new directed graph instance of given initial vertex capacity.
     * 
     * @param vertexCap Initial capacity (number of vertices).
     */
    public DirGraph(int vertexCap) {
        adjlists = new ArrayList<Vertex<T>>(vertexCap);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of vertices in this graph.
     * 
     * @return Number of vertices in this graph.
     */
    public int numberOfVertices() {
        return adjlists.size();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a vertex to this graph.
     * 
     * @param vertex Vertex to be added.
     * @return Number assigned to this vertex in the graph.
     */
    public int addVertex(T vertex) {
        if (!containsVertex(vertex)) {
            adjlists.add(new Vertex<T>(vertex));
        }
        return adjlists.size() - 1;
    }

    /**
     * Tells whether this graph contains a given vertex or not.
     * 
     * @param vertex Vertex to be searched for in this graph.
     * @return True if the given vertex is in this graph, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean containsVertex(T vertex) {
        return adjlists.indexOf(new Vertex<T>(vertex)) != -1;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the internal vertex number for the given vertex.
     * 
     * @param vertex Vertex for which internal number is needed.
     * @return Internal number assigned to the given vertex, -1 if the vertex is not in this graph.
     */
    public int vertexNumberOf(T vertex) {
        return adjlists.indexOf(new Vertex<T>(vertex));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the client-supplied vertex information associated with a given internal vertex number.
     * 
     * @param vertexNumber Internal vertex number.
     * @return Associated client-supplied vertex information.
     */
    public T vertexInfoOf(int vertexNumber) {
        Vertex<T> v = adjlists.get(vertexNumber);
        return v.info;
    }

    /**
     * Tells whether there is an edge from a given vertex (internal number) to another (neighbor).
     * 
     * @param vertexNumber Internal number of vertex.
     * @param nbr Neighbor to which edge is sought.
     * @return True if there is an edge, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean containsEdge(int vertexNumber, Neighbor nbr) {
        Vertex<T> v = adjlists.get(vertexNumber);
        return v.neighbors.contains(nbr);
    }

    /**
     * Adds an edge from a given vertex (internal number) to another (neighbor). Note: If
     * this vertex already has an edge to this neighbor, this method will return without
     * doing anything. In other words, multiple edges are not supported.
     * 
     * @param vertexNumber Internal number of vertex.
     * @param nbr Neighbor to which edge is added.
     */
    public void addEdge(int vertexNumber, Neighbor nbr) {
        Vertex<T> fromVertex = adjlists.get(vertexNumber);
        if (!fromVertex.neighbors.contains(nbr)) {
            fromVertex.neighbors.add(nbr);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the first neighbor of a given vertex.
     * 
     * @param vertexNumber Internal number of vertex.
     * @return First neighbor of given vertex, null if there are no neighbors.
     */
    public Neighbor firstNeighbor(int vertexNumber) {
        Vertex<T> v = adjlists.get(vertexNumber);
        return v.neighbors.first();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the next neighbor of a given vertex.
     * 
     * @param vertexNumber Internal number of vertex.
     * @return Next neighbor of given vertex, relative to an earlier call to
     *          first() or or next(); null if end of neighbors list is reached.
     */
    public Neighbor nextNeighbor(int vertexNumber) {
        Vertex<T> v = adjlists.get(vertexNumber);
        return v.neighbors.next();
    }

    /**
     * Clears this graph of all vertices and edges.
     */
    public void clear() {
        adjlists.clear();
    }


}
```

WeightedUndirGraph.Java    I copied the addEdge method from the superclass and added a weight to it. However, when I implement the code

```
public class WeightedUndirGraph<T> extends UndirGraph<T> {


    public WeightedUndirGraph(){
        super();
    }


    public WeightedUndirGraph(int vertexCap) {
        super(vertexCap);
    }



    public void addEdge(int vertexNumber, Neighbor nbr, int weight) {
        Vertex<T> fromVertex = adjlists.get(vertexNumber);
        if (!fromVertex.neighbors.contains(nbr)) {
            fromVertex.neighbors.add(nbr);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        //create new graph
        WeightedUndirGraph<Object> myGraph = new WeightedUndirGraph<>();
        System.out.println(myGraph.numberOfVertices());

        //create a vertex and add it to graph
        Vertex<Object> vWinnipeg = new Vertex<>("Winnipeg");
        myGraph.addVertex(vWinnipeg);

        //test
        System.out.println(myGraph.numberOfVertices());

        //create neighbors and add it to vertex vWinnipeg
        Neighbor nHalifax = new Neighbor(1,500);
        myGraph.addEdge(0, nHalifax, 500);
        Neighbor nCalgary = new Neighbor(1,500);
        myGraph.addEdge(0, nCalgary, 600);

        //print out info of vertex
        System.out.println(myGraph.vertexInfoOf(0));


    }

}
```

When I print out the info of the vertex vWinnipeg, i am not getting the list of neighbors of the vertex. It just prints out the the vertex memory object.

Comment: How do you get the Vertex object?

Comment: sry. added the class.

Comment: Well, the `info` field in class `Vertex` is of type T. So I guess when you invoke `System.out.println` on it, it prints the reference to the object. Have you tried converting it to String (or change the type of `info` to String)?

Comment: Also, you say you want the list of neighbors, so it seems you should be invoking `System.out.println` on the `neighbors` field from Vertex class.

Comment: Another question I want to ask is why are you defining `'info` and `neighbors` as `protected` ? You do not have any other class in this sample extending `Vertex`. Note that you will not have access to these fields outside of this package, unless the accessor `extends` Vertex.

Comment: no reason. that class is from a data structures textbook.

Comment: If the package you are using, has source code available online, please link to it. This code does not compile, again due to UndirGraph<T> not being defined.